# Cygwin Openssl uninstall

Tags: windows, openssl, cygwin

I'm a complete newbie on cygwin, it was placed on our server to configure ssh or openssl, not by me :-) .

- server: windows 2003 SP2
- cygwin: (cannot find version, but it says GNU bash, version 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin))
- OpenSSL-Win32: version 1.0.2a

In the cygwin terminal I see two things that disturb and confuse me:
If I open the cygwin terminal I can type

```
>$ openssl    
>cygwin warning: MS-DOS style path detected: C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg ...(etc)
```

So the cygwin can see the other openssl install. I would be happy with that if I would not get the following:

```
>OpenSSL> version    
>OpenSSL 0.9.8t 18 Jan 2012
```

So, there seems to be be 2 versions of openssl installed, even though I think that this 0.9.8t version doesn't seem to do anything.

How do I uninstall this openSSL version?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall any package from Cygwin, run [setup.exe](https://cygwin.com/install.html) (which you should already have), and on the package selection screen you should search for `"openssl"`. After that you should click the round arrow icon for the packages until it says "Uninstall", then continue.

Anyway the warning indicates that you run the win32 version, and not the cygwin package. To make sure of that, you should run this command: `which openssl`. This will print the path to the executable. If this path is not what you want, then use an absolute path at the command line. E.g: `/cygdrive/c/path_to_openssl/openssl.exe`.